# Is this a valid shebang line?

Tags: shebang

I have the following question about UNIX:

> What else is needed when the top line goes
>
> > ```
> > #!\bin\awk -f
> > ```
>
> ```
>   to make it run as a command?
> ```

I am thinking whatever the name of the script is it need to be given permission using chmod to make it run.

Comment: yes it uses \ I forward slash.

Comment: So one thing that is needed is to replace `\` for `/`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The first line with the "#!" will be a full pathname to the program to be executed.

Pathnames in Linux have the forward slash between directories.

i.e.:

```
#!/bin/awk -f
```

or

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
```

The first script would be run the script program using `awk`, the second using `bash`, the third using `perl`.

You'll also have to make the file executable with:

```
$ chmod +x myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 5):

`#!\bin\awk -f` is a valid shebang line, but it isn't a useful one. It declares that the file must be interpreted by the program called `\bin\awk` in the current directory. Thus, to answer the question literally, there are two ways to run that file as a command:

- Create a file called `\bin\awk` in the current directory, presumably by copying or linking some version of awk. Also, the script needs to be made executable.

  ```
  ln -s /bin/awk '\bin\awk'
  chmod +x /path/to/script
  /path/to/script
  ```
- Invoke awk explicitly.

  ```
  awk -f /path/to/script
  ```

If modifying the file is allowed, then the shebang line should be edited to make sense: replace the backslashes by slashes. And make the file executable (which is undoubtedly the intended answer, but merely doing that would not be a correct answer).